# Is using a VAO essential in opengl 3.1 with forward compatibility flag set

Tags: opengl, shader

I am creating a program and I am using VBO to bind vertex data. I am not using a VAO. When I bind the buffer and do glVertexAttribPointer in draw function, I get **opengl error 1282**. I googled it and I think I need to use a VAO from opengl 3.0 onward. I want to know if its really necessary to use a VAO in opengl 3.0 onward. cannot I just create vbo and bind and use it directly in my draw function instead of using a vbo

PS. I am creating a 3.1 opengl context with `WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB` bit set to WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB. If I dont do this, it creates backward compatible context and works fine. But I need a forward compatible context. I am creating the context with following attributes

```
    int attribs[] =
    {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 1,
        WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
       0
    };
```

Following is my draw function. I get error at bolded line

```
void DrawFunc(MtColor& color, float* matrix, GLuint bufferIndex, int numVertices, GLenum mode)
{
    GLuint e = glGetError();
    glUseProgram(m_Program);
    e = glGetError();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferIndex);
    e = glGetError();

    // Now set uniforms.
    glUniform4fv(m_uniforms[COLOR_HANDLE], 1, color.AsFloat());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(m_uniforms[MVP_HANDLE], 1, false, matrix);
    e = glGetError();
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_attributes[POSITION_HANDLE]);
    e = glGetError();
    glVertexAttribPointer(m_attributes[POSITION_HANDLE], 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    **e = glGetError();**
    glDrawArrays(mode, 0, numVertices);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(m_attributes[POSITION_HANDLE]);
```

}

Comment: Why do you pick 3.1? I could understand picking 3.2, since that's a version used by older versions of MacOSX, or 3.3 since that's the last 3.x version. But there's no reason to stick with 3.1 specifically.

Comment: ya I was just trying with 3.1. After changing code, now my code works with 3.2+ opengl also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a forward compatible context then you need a VAO.

However you can create and bind one and then forget about it. It's not recommended to do so but it works.

```
//before uploading your model
int vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
```

However with proper use the draw function can be reduced to:

```
void DrawFunc(MtColor& color, float* matrix, GLuint vao, int numVertices, GLenum mode)
{
    GLuint e = glGetError();
    glUseProgram(m_Program);
    e = glGetError();

    // Now set uniforms.
    glUniform4fv(m_uniforms[COLOR_HANDLE], 1, color.AsFloat());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(m_uniforms[MVP_HANDLE], 1, false, matrix);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArrays(mode, 0, numVertices);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

}
```

Comment: so I just create the vao and keep it binded. but dont use it at all and still it should work? Basically I have a lot of code which was working with opengl 2.0 . I need to make it work with 3.1 forward compatibility context. They have used vbo but not vao. I have updated shaders and all, but I dont want to change the code fully.

Comment: The quick fix is indeed create one, bind it and then forget about it.

Comment: is there any official opengl document I can see which states that using vao is made essential in opengl 3.1+. I tried but could not find any. Its working for me but I need a reference for proof check

Comment: check out the 3.1 spec page 309: https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec31.20090528.pdf#page309 "Calling VertexAttribPointer when no buffer object or *no vertex array object* is bound will generate an INVALID_OPERATION error"